# element type is invalid expected a string or a class/function but got object

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**routes.js**

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import SignIn from '~/pages/SignIn';
import SignUp from '~/pages/SignUp';

import Dashboard from '~/pages/Dashboard';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default (isSigned = false) => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {isSigned ? (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
          <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

**App.js**

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import createRouter from './routes';

export default function App() {
  const isSigned = useSelector((state) => state.auth.signed);

  const Routes = createRouter(isSigned);

  return <Routes />;
}
```

I use react navigation v5, I am still a beginner and I was studying its new version. However, I can't define the reason for this error. The error returns that it expects a function or class, but is this not a function?

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUeca.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change routes.js like this:

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import SignIn from '~/pages/SignIn';
import SignUp from '~/pages/SignUp';

import Dashboard from '~/pages/Dashboard';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default ({ isSigned }) => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {isSigned ? (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
          <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

Change App.js like this :

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import Routes from './routes';

export default function App() {
  const isSigned = useSelector((state) => state.auth.signed);

  return <Routes isSigned={isSigned} />;
}
```